# Firebase function finishes 1-2 times successfully, then throws error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, es6-promise

I use batches to write into `firestore` and my `firebase-functions` code always executes successfully on the first attempt.

```
i  functions: Beginning execution of "myFunction"
i  functions: Finished "myFunction" in ~1s
i  functions: Beginning execution of "myFunction"
   API fetch ...
   Amount of records to process: 3600
   filled batch (amount of writes: 490)
   filled batch (amount of writes: 490)
   ...
   All batches commited to Firebase
   imported batch
   imported batch
   ...
i  functions: Finished "myFunction" in ~33s
```

The error always occurs on the second OR third execution of the function with the following error message:

```
Unhandled error Error: Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed.
```

My approach to use batches consists of two steps.

1. I create an array with batches and pass 490 writes into each.
2. I execute every commit operation within `await Promise.all()`

I guess that my mistake is inside step 2. I tried promise chaining and async await:

async/await:

```js
try {
    await Promise.all(batches.map(batch => batch.commit()))
    console.log('All batches commited to Firebase')
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

promise chaining:

```js
await Promise.all(batches.map(batch => {
    return batch.commit().then(function () {
        console.log("imported batch")
    });
}))
    .then(console.log('All batches commited to Firebase'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

The batches array itself is being created like this, I call the following function multiple times in a loop:

```
function useBatches(collectionRef, action, type, docId, data) {
    
    const docRef = collectionRef.doc(docId);

    switch(action) {
        case 'delete':
            batches[batchIndex].delete(docRef);
            break;
        case 'update':
            batches[batchIndex].update(docRef, data);
            break;
        case 'set':
            batches[batchIndex].set(docRef, data);
            break;
    }
    batchSizeCounter++;
    totalWritesToDo--

    // create batches
    if (batchSizeCounter === BATCH_SIZE) {
        console.log(`filled batch (amount of writes: ${batchSizeCounter})`)
        batches.push(db.batch());
        batchIndex++;
        batchSizeCounter = 0;
    }

    // inform about last batch was filled
    if (totalWritesToDo === 0) {
        console.log(`filled batch (amount of writes: ${batchSizeCounter})`)
        return;
    }
}
```

I am very thankful for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete minimal code.  We can't see at all how you are creating and dealing with the batches.  We should be able to take the code your provide and run it for ourselves to observe the same behavior.  I suggest reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for the feedback, I have updated my question

Comment: I still don't see where you are declaring `batches`, so I can't copy this code to run it.  All you are doing here is pushing things into it and committing.  The error  message is telling you that you can't commit a batch object after it's already been committed.  You might want to simplify this code to make it more clear how these batches actually work.

Comment: The strange thing is that it happens after the 2nd or 3rd time. The first time is always successful.

Comment: Yeah, you are doing something wrong here, but there is not enough information to know exactly what, since you are not showing all the code.